# When is the word *LEV* לב first mentioned in the Torah?

Tags: sources-mekorot

I was not able to find this information anywhere, so am positing the question here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Just checking a non-vowelized page of Chumash [like mechon-mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x01.htm) and doing Ctrl+F, we get Genesis 6:5

> וירא ה', כי רבה רעת האדם בארץ, וכל-יצר מחשבת **לבו**, רק רע כל-היום

God saw that ... all the plans of man's heart were constantly bad.

Of course that's conjugated "libo", "his heart." If you want just "lev", fast-forward to the end of the Flood story, 8:21:

> כי יצר **לב** האדם רע מנעריו

> The inclination of man's heart his evil from his youth

Afraid those may not be the uplifting ones you had in mind ... but early Genesis has a lot of human failure ...

Comment: Thank you. I did try Mechon-Memre but for some odd reason the browser was alerting me to coding errors. Ironically. 

Re; Ki Yatzar Lev Ha-Adam Ra Meneurav - I read this to mean *He CREATED man's heart to be evil from the (point) of his youth.* This, perhaps to give us the starting point of return via discernment. 

Todah rabbah :)

Comment: @AdamaTova vowelization -- it's yetzer = "nature", not yatzar.

Comment: One could find this information in the concordance about any word.

Comment: One could read YATZAR and also to read YETZER. @Shalom. And if not, why?